# What is a good way to auto-generate an attribute value?

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design

We are building an application that includes a lot of automation. Part of the initialization of this task is to specify the rules for generating specific attribute values. But it is difficult to find an intuitive way of doing this. My initial design below is loosely based on the iTunes playlist generator. I'm trying to come up with an alternative design to test. Does anyone know of an alternative way of doing this? 
[image]

Comment: What is the step 2 here ?

Comment: Step 2 is the increment for the number range - 1,3,5...

Comment: What are you struggling with? An intuitive way for the user to indicate he wants to create a new attribute (the plus sign in your case)? Or being clear about what each type of attribute does (Text vs. Number Range vs. List)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is related to your question.

I've used [DTM Data Generator](http://www.sqledit.com/dg/) for generating data (aka attributes?). There are screenshots that give you an idea of how the UI works.

A quick search on 'data generation tool' found [Generatedata.com](http://www.generatedata.com/#generator). I played around with it. It isn't nearly as powerful as DTM.